# Comment prononcer « de grandes amours » ?

Tags: prononciation

Si j’ai bien compris la règle, le mot « amour » devient féminin au pluriel, donc la locution « de grandes amours » me semble tout à fait juste, cependant je n’arrive pas à la prononcer. Quand je fais la liaison, le « d » disparaît, et vice versa. Sinon, les lettres « des » deviennent « tz » qui me paraît faux. C’est quoi la bonne prononciation?
Merci d’avance

Comment: Si je me trompe de locution, dites moi la bonne graphie s’il vous plait.

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que la majorité des gens diront [dəɡʁɑ̃dzamuʁ], ne prononçant pas vraiment le « e » et en faisant juste entendre le « d ». Le « s » ne s'entend que parce qu'on fait la liaison avec la voyelle du mot suivant. C'est à dire que si on fait un  découpage en syllabes on a [də] [ɡʁɑ̃d] [zamuʁ].
On peut aussi vouloir faire entendre le « e » de « grandes » par souci d'élocution, pour le besoin d'avoir le bon nombre de pieds en poésie, etc. et donc prononcer [dəɡʁɑ̃dəzamuʁ].

Attention il ne faut pas croire que le mot amour soit toujours féminin au pluriel.

> « Au pluriel, selon une règle traditionnelle, il est ordinairement féminin ; en réalité, l’usage n’est pas fixé et le pluriel d’amour est des deux genres<sup>1</sup> ».

Même de grands poètes ont parfois utilisé le mot au masculin pluriel <sup>2</sup>. Et dans la langue courante, et surtout de nos jours, on le trouve le plus souvent au masculin <sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  Grevisse, § 253, 2°, 10<sup>e</sup> édition.

<sup><sup>2</sup>  *Souris à tes premiers amours*. (Alfred De Musset) —  *De ces amours historiquement constatés avec une grande dame, il lui était resté ce drap de lit* (Victor Hugo)</sup> 

<sup>3</sup> *Je m’étonnerais, si je ne savais que les grandes âmes sont seules capables de grands amours* (George Sand). — *j’ai passé ma vie cloîtrée parce que je n’ai eu de grands amours que pour des hommes qui étaient terriblement jaloux* (Marcel Proust) — *De grands amours peuvent ainsi naître dès la maternelle !* ([Revue Parents](https://www.parents.fr/enfant/education-et-vie-sociale/vie-sociale/vie-amoureuse))</sup>